# Keras set_weights do not change predictions by changing the weights exorbitantly

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I am changing the weight_matrix that I get from calling layer.get_weights() and then using set_weights() I change a couple of weights and when I call get_weights() again it shows the weights I changed in set_weights. However, it does not change my predictions at all. Even though I change them drastically.

Also, if I call model.compile and then call layer.set_weights it says 'int' object has no attribute 'set_weights'

I am confused what's going wrong.

```
layer = 1
hiddenU = 16
val_dictionary = {}
model = keras.models.Sequential(name = 'LSTM')
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(hiddenU, input_shape = xt.shape[1:], return_sequences = layer > 1))
model.add(Dense(2))
adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=1e-4)
model.compile(loss= lambda y, yp: (pinball(y, yp, 1)), optimizer = 'adam')
model.load_weights('Weights/LSTMGetWeights')
for layer in model.layers:
    weights = layer.get_weights()
print(weights)
    [array([[ 0.36053008, -0.25284126],
       [ 0.37837738, -0.5382352 ],
       [-0.05943123,  0.19144805],
       [ 0.3131915 ,  0.7109782 ],
       [ 0.23572737, -0.11478594],
       [ 0.10371532,  0.6173115 ],
       [ 0.9760161 ,  1.4972438 ],
       [ 0.2379393 , -0.0071888 ],
       [ 0.55228376,  0.46662283],
       [ 1.2852958 ,  0.475782  ],
       [ 0.13585456,  0.5095823 ],
       [-0.13454953, -0.7498165 ],
       [ 0.00282927, -0.53929615],
       [-0.21484761,  0.08239145],
       [ 0.9378741 ,  0.8509973 ],
       [-0.46459877,  0.21304554]], dtype=float32), array([-0.01857078,  0.26882732], dtype=float32)]

layer.set_weights([np.array([[ 0.36053008, 23.023],
       [ 0.37837738, -0.5382352 ],
       [-0.05943123,  0.19144805],
       [ 0.3131915 ,  0.7109782 ],
       [ 0.23572737, -0.11478594],
       [ 0.10371532,  0.6173115 ],
       [ 0.9760161 ,  1.4972438 ],
       [ 0.2379393 , -0.0071888 ],
       [ 0.55228376,  0.46662283],
       [ 1.2852958 ,  0.475782  ],
       [ 0.13585456,  0.5095823 ],
       [-0.13454953, -0.7498165 ],
       [ 0.00282927, -0.53929615],
       [-0.21484761,  0.08239145],
       [ 0.9378741 ,  0.8509973 ],
       [-0.46459877,  0.21304554]], dtype=np.float32), np.array([-0.01857078,  0.26882732], dtype=np.float32)])
```

Now when I call layer.get_weights it returns

```
[array([[ 3.6053008e-01,  2.3023001e+01],
       [ 3.7837738e-01, -5.3823519e-01],
       [-5.9431229e-02,  1.9144805e-01],
       [ 3.1319150e-01,  7.1097821e-01],
       [ 2.3572737e-01, -1.1478594e-01],
       [ 1.0371532e-01,  6.1731148e-01],
       [ 9.7601610e-01,  1.4972438e+00],
       [ 2.3793930e-01, -7.1887998e-03],
       [ 5.5228376e-01,  4.6662283e-01],
       [ 1.2852958e+00,  4.7578201e-01],
       [ 1.3585456e-01,  5.0958228e-01],
       [-1.3454953e-01, -7.4981648e-01],
       [ 2.8292700e-03, -5.3929615e-01],
       [-2.1484761e-01,  8.2391448e-02],
       [ 9.3787408e-01,  8.5099733e-01],
       [-4.6459877e-01,  2.1304554e-01]], dtype=float32), array([-0.01857078,  0.26882732], dtype=float32)]
```

The updated weights. 
However, when I call model.predict it does not change the predictions at all. Even if I completely change the weight matrix.

Comment: You only seem to change the second column of the first row to 23.023. It is perfectly possible that doesn't change the outcome. Have you tried to really mess up the whole weight array?

Comment: I did. I changed a bunch of them and it doesn't update the predictions